# How to fix rspec "undefined method `validate_presence_of'" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

When I run `rspec` I get this error:

```
Failures:

  1) User
    Failure/Error: it { should validate_presence_of :email  }

  NoMethodError:
      undefined method `validate_presence_of' for <RSpec::ExampleGroups::User:0x007f8177ff3408>
    # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.00168 seconds (files took 2.72 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:5 # User
```

But how can fix it?

This is my Gemfile:

```
group :development, :test do
 gem 'byebug'
 gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.4', '>= 3.4.1'
 gem "factory_girl_rails", "~> 4.0"
 gem 'capybara', '~> 2.6', '>= 2.6.2'
 # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a       debugger console
gem 'byebug'
end

group :test do
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', require: false
end
```

This is my model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :email, presence: true
end
```

And my user_spec:

```
require 'rails_helper'

 RSpec.describe User, type: :model do
   #pending "add some examples to (or delete) #{__FILE__}"
   it { should validate_presence_of :email  }   

 end
```

Comment: [May be of help](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda/issues/203)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [undefined method \`validate\_presence\_of' for RSpec::ExampleGroups::User::Validations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31276625/undefined-method-validate-presence-of-for-rspecexamplegroupsuservalidati)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'd recommend reading http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html. It's chock-full of great tips for you. It's not necessary to say "Help me please" since that's what this site is for. We expect well written questions, not begging. Please take the time to format your question and use appropriate capitalization; Those pay off.

Comment: Did my answer work for you? please let us know. and consider mark as best answer. Thanks

Comment: Thanks  for your answers and recommendations :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**OUTDATED:**

Please consider using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61292450/1240330)

Add this to your rails_helper.rb

```
require 'shoulda/matchers'
```

Your specs are missing shoulda matcher's methods.

Please take a look to this [thread](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda/issues/203). Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you single add in shoulda_matchers_helper.rb this:                                         Shoulda::Matchers.configure do |config|
  config.integrate do |with|
    with.test_framework :rspec
    with.library :rails
  end
end

Comment: It doesn't work anymore, please consider using https://stackoverflow.com/a/61292450/1240330

Answer (score 12):

Check if you have added configuration in `rails_helper`.

if `require 'shoulda/matchers'` doesn't work, add following config in `spec/rails_helper.rb`

```
Shoulda::Matchers.configure do |config|
  config.integrate do |with|
    with.test_framework :rspec
    with.library :rails
  end
end
```

For more information, refer [shoulda-matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers#rails-apps).

Answer (score 2):

If you're testing a model or a form (meaning that your form has model-like properties by including `include ActiveModel::Model`) - specifying the type of spec file will help remove this issue, i.e. `type: :model`

```
RSpec.describe TestForm, type: :model do
  subject { described_class.new(user_id) }
  let(:user_id) { 1 }

  it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:whatever) }
end
```